# Connecting valgrind to GDB

Tags: c, gdb, valgrind

The official valgrind documentation(https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver) provides us with the following instructions:

"
3.2. Debugging your program using Valgrind gdbserver and GDB
...
3.2.1. Quick Start: debugging in 3 steps
The simplest way to get started is to run Valgrind with the flag --vgdb-error=0. Then follow the on-screen directions, which give you the precise commands needed to start GDB and connect it to your program.
"

I execute `valgrind --vgdb-error=0 ./badcode` and get

```
==101901== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==101901==   /path/to/gdb ./badcode
==101901== and then give GDB the following command
==101901==   target remote | /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=101901
```

After that I open GDB `gdb badcode`, type in `start` and copy the command valgrind gave me:

```
target remote | /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=101901
```

The output is:

```
A program is being debugged already.  Kill it? (y or n)
```

If I chose `y` it follows with

```
Remote debugging using | /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid
=101901
sh: 1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb: not found
Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: Connection terminated by the other party.
```

And if I chose `n` I get

```
`Program not killed.
(gdb)`
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't enter `start`, only the commands valgrind listed.

Comment: I can not reproduce it. As @ssbssa said, you shouldn't enter `start`, but even when you do, pressing `y` afterwards it should work (it is supposed to kills the process you started with gdb and attaches to the valgrind process). Does `/usr/bin/vgdb` exist on your system? If not, does `vgdb` exist somewhere else? Maybe you should mention which system and valgrind version you are using.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 `target remote` doesn't support starting new processes, and `vgdb` has only recently started to gain support for `target extended-remote` which is required for starting new processes.  With a `remote` target the inferior is already running at the point GDB connects, you can just `continue` to start running.

Comment: @Andrew "`target remote` doesn't support starting new processes", yes, but why should it be? He shouldn't start a new process in gdb at all, not with `start` nor `target ...`, he should just connect to the existing process started with valgrind. (Maybe i completely misunderstand what you said,  but i don't get how your comment is related to my comment)

Comment: @12431234123412341234123
The guy from this YouTube tutorial [link](https://youtu.be/NDpE707jYHc?t=450) entered the `start` command and did not even get `A program is being debugged already.  Kill it? (y or n)` message.

I do have `vgdb` executable file in `/usr/bin` directory. When I typed in gdb the command `target remote | usr/bin/vgdb --pid=115941` instead of the command, recommended by Valgrind itself (the one I used in the initial question), it gave me the same result.

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
valgrind-3.15.0

Comment: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb` That is looking for `vgdb` in `/usr/lib/bin`, not in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123
*/usr/bin/vgdb*
Yes, youre correct, thank you!
However GDB doesn't work as I expected. At first attempt it can't get attached to the code:
`
(gdb) step
Cannot find bounds of current function
(gdb)
`
At second attempt (quit GDB and launched it again) looks like that everything works but then it crushes at first `printf` operator:
`
0x0000000000109162 in main () at badcode.c:7
7         if (x < 10)
(gdb) step
8             printf("First\n");
(gdb) step
__GI__IO_puts (str=0x10a004 "First") at ioputs.c:33
33 ioputs.c: There is no such file or directory.
`

Comment: @12431234123412341234123
**How did you install gdb and valgrind? Is one of them containered or in a VM (docker, flatpack, VM, ....)?**
As far as I remember I've used `sudo apt install` for both.

Comment: **Does `/usr/bin/vgdb` Work?**
Yes, kind of :)
**If so, you should ask a new question. And add a bit more information about your environment.**
Yes, I'll try again, thank you very much :D

Comment: @Fyodor That's because in the tutorial he entered `start` at a paging prompt saying `--Type <RET> for more info, q to quit, c to continue without paging--`, which just ignores this command, and is just wrong. Telling from this video he seems to be a gdb beginner himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gehardh said, the problem is, that the path valgrind tells you is wrong. It tells you it is at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb`, which is equivalent to `/usr/lib/bin/vgdb` and not `/usr/bin/vgdb` where it should be. Using `/usr/bin/vgdb` should fix that problem. A other minor point is, you don't need and better shouldn't start the program in gdb with `start`. In other words, start gdb and type: `target remote | /usr/bin/vgdb`, without typing `start` first. (In case it is the only valgrind process, the pid is not needed, otherwise add the `--pid=<pid>` to the command).

I found [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=942532) bugreport where valgrind prints the wrong path, but it is older and should be fixed. Maybe you should update your system (in case it is the same bug)?

Comment: You've got a typo, friend, "Using `/usr/lib/bin/vgdb` should fix that problem."